# How to update a json file with only new elements?

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

I recieve a json from another page with many elements, one of them is an id. What I want to do is create a new json with only the ids, so here is what I am doing:

First, the json is decoded to store in server as files. It is stored in an array. From there I store all the ids in another array, this is the simplified version of what I'm doing:

```
$json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('path/to/file.json'));
foreach($json_array as $arr){
$ids[] = $arr['id'];
}

file_put_contents('ids.json', json_encode($ids));
```

So far it is doing what I want, I got a json with all the id's. The problem is, my json file updates and only shows the last 50 items. So whenever this is called, I get the last 50 id's. For example, if I got 50 items, then my json has id 1 to id 50, but if I got 60 items, it shows from id 10 to id 60, so the first 10 ids are replaced and gone.

I would like to keep those first 10 ids, but still update with new ids and avoid duplicates. The problem is that in the example I gave, items 10 to 50 are the same, and only the last 10 are new. I'm not sure if this is possible. To be clear:

**My current json:** id's from 1 - 50.

**Update json:** items 10 - 60 (the items from 10 to 50 are the same as before).

**What I would like my json to keep:** id's from 1 - 60, with no duplicates. (Keep this everytime there is an update, so if json has 100 - 150 items, my ids json would store ids from 1 to 150).

I gave numbers as example to be more clear, it doesnt really update with 10 new items, it could be any random number. Oh and I'm working with Codeigniter, if that's any help.

Thanks for your help and time, I have googled everywhere for a solution, but I'm not exactly sure what to look for.

Comment: Did you tried to get any error with [json_last_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) ? maybe it will help ya if there is effectively an error.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand how would that help? The code is working, the problem is it is replacing old items with new ones. Is it not supposed to do that?

Comment: I'm not sure your code is working :) see `foreach($json_array as $arr){ $ids[] = $arr['id'] }` there is a missing `;` after `$ids[] = $arr['id']`

Comment: oh! I'm sorry that is a typo, that's not my actual code, it's just a simplified version to keep things more clear :)

Comment: mhh, maybe you should post the entire code, but well, try to put one `var_dump(json_last_error());` after `json_decode` and `json_encode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to read in the target file, decode it's contents, check if the array contains the new item, and if not, append it to the array.

```
$ids = json_decode(file_get_contents('ids.json'));
$json_array = json_decode(file_get_contents('path/to/file.json'));
foreach($json_array as $arr){
    if (!in_array($arr['id'], $ids)) $ids[] = $arr['id'];
}

file_put_contents('ids.json', json_encode($ids));
```

Comment: That's very clever! Should I also add FILE_APPEND as third parameter to the file_put_contents() ?

Comment: Not in this case, no.  You are reading in the whole file, so you are already effectively appending.  If you do `FILE_APPEND` it will just be invalid JSON or lots of repetitions.